# Redirect React HTTP traffic to HTTPS GCP

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, devops

Currently my ReactJS web application is running on Google Cloud App Engine flexible environment.
I deploy the app using `gcloud deploy` command.

If I want to access my website I need to add in my url the `https`.

How can I make that all my HTTP request are redirected to the same route on HTTPS?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following react-https-redirect api to redirect from http to https.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-https-redirect